# Python Contour Plot/HeatMap

Tags: python, heatmap, contourf

I have x and y coordinates in a df  from LoL matches and i want to create a contour plot or heat map to show where the player normally moves in a match.
Does any one know how can I do it?

Comment: This is already done for LoL matches [here](https://demoriarty.github.io/LeagueHeatmap/) based on this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/exo1mr/so_i_made_a_league_of_legends_heatmap_viewer/) you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

A contour plot or heat map needs 3 values. You have to provide x, y and z values in order to plot a contour since x and y give the position and z gives the value of the variable you want to show the contour of as a variable of x and y.

If you want to show the movement of the players as a function of time you should look at matplotlib's animations. Or if you want to show the "players density field" you have to calculate it.

Comment: i dont need the animation, how do i calculate the player density field?

Comment: You can for example create a grid and calculate the number of player in each square of the grid and the density per each square would be nplayers/squareArea. You will end up with a 2d array that you can show using only.matshow

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
from scipy import ndimage
from matplotlib import cm


#select the x and y coordinates
x = df['x']
y = df['y']
nbins= 512 
k = gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x,y]))
xi, yi = np.mgrid[0:512, 0:512] #size of the image/map in px
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

im = mpimg.imread("map.png")#Put he background image


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))

ax2 = fig.add_subplot()



ax2.contourf(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), alpha=0.5, cmap=cm.jet, extent=[1, -1, 1, -1])


ax2.set_xlim(0, 512)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 512)


ax2.axis('off')


plt.imshow(im, extent=[0, 512, 0, 512])
plt.savefig(f'Enemies/Clausura/{team}/{team} Stats/{summoner[1]} Early.png', dpi=None, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```